# Flexible Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am trying to create a flexible dictionary which is based on an xml file. I use xmlDigester with some rules and everything goes good until when i am trying to parse the values of my dictionary.

Above is my object classes which create the Dictionary with the XMLdigister:

```
@interface slideInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *appname;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *marketinfos;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *questionMarket;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theText;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * mrtInfos;

-(void)addInfo:(marketInfos*)market;
-(void)questionMarket:(answerHandler*)qMarket;

@end
```

The .m file

```
@implementation slideInfo

@synthesize id, version, appname, marketinfos, questionMarket, mrtInfos, theText;

- (id)init {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.mrtInfos = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addInfo:(marketInfos*)market
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", market.name, market.image];
    [mrtInfos setObject:market forKey:key];

}

-(void)questionMarket:(answerHandler*)qMarket
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", qMarket.name, qMarket.image, qMarket.question, qMarket.answer];
    [mrtInfos setObject:qMarket forKey:key];
    theText = qMarket.question;
    NSLog(@"Dic: %@" , theText);
}


@end
```

The answeHandler.h

```
@interface answerHandler : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *question;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *answer;

-(NSString *)marketString;

@end
```

and the .m

```
@implementation answerHandler

@synthesize id, name, image, question, answer;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSLog(@"answerHandler init");
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)marketString {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@" ,id, name, image, question, answer];
}

@end
```

Now my question is how can i retrieve a specific value from my dictionary? Everything i tried returns null. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Main question is what data you have to retrieve/search on dictionary. Why you don't use the id object to be the key inside the NSDictionary?

```
-(void)addInfo:(marketInfos*)market
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", market.id];
    [mrtInfos setObject:market forKey:key];

}
```

Then use that id to search in your dictionary;

```
-(marketInfos*)objectFromDictionary:(NSNumber*)id
{

    return =  [mrtInfos objectForKey:id];

}
```

Comment: I have a lot of different nodes in my xml file. I want specifically to parse let say the question string from dictionary